# stopping several commands that I initiated by bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have written the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

topic_list=$(echo $1 | tr ":" "\n")
for topic in ${topic_list}
    do
        echo "calling hz on "${topic}
        name=$(basename "${topic}")
        run_command ${topic} >&1 | tee ${name}.log
    done
```

Originally I just called

```
run_command ${topic} >&1 | tee ${name}.log
```

which run the command I wanted with the appropriate parameter, and put the result in a file, while showing the output to the console. When I wanted to stop it I typed Ctrl-C

However now I need to run this command several times for several topics at the same time. (Therefore the script)

I have two problems with this:

1. I don't think it is ok to show the output of multiple runs of the command to the console, so I need to modify this so that the output goes to only a file. So for this I suppose I will do `run_command ${topic} > ${name}.log`
2. The most important is, how do I stop these commands?

If I run this script `run_command` will run at once, so what is the best way to stop all at once , once I am done?

Note: I though of doing ps and kill but:

- When I do ps, nothing shows, so I do `ps -a` and there it is `run_command`. However
- It seems that when I run `run_command`, other processes start as well, because I can see others including a `sudo`, these all dissapeared when I do ctrl-c of the command.

Yes, in fact `run_command` is a shell script that calls another shell script that calls another shell script that calls a compiled program. These others are run as root, while `run_command` is run by me as a user.
Would killing `run_command` accomplish terminating the processes?
So how can I kill the multiple `run_commands`?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to kill many processes with the same name in Linux is via command:

```
killall <process name>
```

You can use regex, send different signals, etc.

**NB!** Do not use this command in UNIX because it will do what name say, kill ALL processes in operating system.

Comment: I am using ubuntu linux. Would that be ok? Also `run_command` is a script and with `ps aux` it appears as `/bin/bah /usr/bin/run_command` . How do I kill it in that case?

Comment: to be on the safe side you can try `killall -i /usr/bin/run_command` (interactive, to ask before kill the process)